# Ajax not passing strings or arrays to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, post

I have this jQuery method

```
var params = {
    pGroupIdents: $.param({ pGroupIdents: groupIdents }),
    pIsNew: isNew,
    pNewTypeCategoryIdent: $(DetailsNewTypeCategory_Select).val(),
    pNewTypeTitle: $(DetailsNewTypeTitle_TB).val(),
    pExistingTypeIdent: $(DetailsExistingTypeCategory_Select).val(),
    pNote: isNew ? $(DetailsNewTypeNote_TB).val() : $(DetailsExistingTypeNote_Select).val()
};
var json = JSON.stringify(params);
$.ajax({
    url: "/Activities/PostExtraCurricular/SetExtraCurricular/",
    type: "POST",
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
    .always(function () {
    })
    .success(function (data) {
    })
    .fail(function () {
    });
```

Posting to this method

```
    public JsonResult SetExtraCurricular(Int32[] pGroupIdents, bool pIsNew, int pNewTypeCategoryIdent, String pNewTypeTitle, int pExistingTypeIdent, String pNote)
```

And the stringified data is this

```
"{"pGroupIdents":["12033","12025","12030"],"pIsNew":true,"pNewTypeCategoryIdent":"2","pNewTypeTitle":"title","pExistingTypeIdent":"2","pNote":"note"}"
```

In the controller the `int` parameters work just fine, but both the `String` parameters and `Int32[]` parameters are always null.

Ive tried; adding `[HttpPost]`, `traditional: true`, `string` vs `String`, `int[]` vs `Int32[]` vs `IEnumerable[int]`

Ive done all this before just dandy but ive no idea whats not working here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, for this I created a wrapper class to pass my variables in, as I have done before, but for a similar problem it was solved by `parseInt()` on the client side, that I'm guessing was the issue here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not stringify the params. Just sending through the object is fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Activities/PostExtraCurricular/SetExtraCurricular/",
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
})
```